# How can I use oracle variable binding within IN-keyword

Tags: java, sql, oracle, groovy, variable-binding

I use variable binding in ORACLE with java/groovy like these:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = :id"
sqlConnection.query(sql, [id: 111])
```

It works perfect. But when I try the same with an IN-keyword I got an error:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id IN(:ids)"
sqlConnection.query(sql, [ids: [111, 222, 333]])
```

When I execute it I got this error:
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type

Has anybody an idea?

Comment: You can replace `sqlConnection.query(sql, [ids: [111, 222, 333]])`

With 
`List<Integer> ids = Arrays.asList(111, 222, 333)`
`sqlConnection.query(sql, [ids: ids])`

Comment: Please let me know, if you still face any problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work like that. It is possible only if you have a bind variable fore each of the members of the list.
An alternative would be not to use a bind variable at all in case of the in list, but just pass the whole list as a string to Oracle.